# container-fluid not filling screen width correctly on Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I have some container-fluid divs on my site and I have been viewing the site up until this point in Safari. Im using Bootstrap 4 and it is displayed incorrectly in my version of chrome.

Here is one of the container-fluid in safari:
[view from safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI6fN.png)

And here is the view from Chrome: [view from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EqXu.jpg)

How do I make it go the full width of the screen on chrome?

Here is some of the HTML

```
<div class="site">
    <div class="container my-5 site-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="carousel slide" data-interval="9000" data-ride="carousel" id="frontpageCarousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="carousel-item active"><img alt="Giant_head_brighter_500_x_600" class="d-block img-fluid" src="Images/Front-Slideshow/Giant_head_500_x_500.jpg">
                        </div>


                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img alt="final_shot_with_bottle_500_x_600.jpg" class="d-block img-fluid" src="Images/Front-Slideshow/giant_button_500_x_500.jpg">
                        </div>

                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img alt="final_shot_with_bottle_500_x_600.jpg" class="d-block img-fluid" src="Images/Front-Slideshow/two_figures_500_x_500.jpg">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <h1>We build custom props.</h1>


                <p>We utilize a network of the best prop makers in the movie, commercial, trade show, event, advertising, marketing and themed entertainment industries to create amazing props.</p>


                <p>We select the best-suited veteran artisans and fabricators for your project — artisans who fabricate for some of the most popular TV shows, the biggest movies and some of the world’s best known companies, like Disney, Universal Studios, NASA, Red Bull, Mazda, JetBlue, Dior and many more.</p>


                <p><b>We're great at what we do and we're here to do it for you.</b>
                </p>


                <div class="text-center">
                    <a class=" btn btn-primary" href="request-estimate.html" style="margin-top: 15px">Request an Estimate</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="container-fluid testimonial">
        <div class="spacer">
        </div>


        <div class="container my-5">
            <p>"Absolutely blown away by your team's work and professionalism. Client thrilled. Great execution. Great teamwork."</p>
            <i>- Project Managers, Derse</i>

            <p>[Derse is ranked as a Top 10 Experiential/Event Marketing Agency by Advertising Age]</p>
        </div>


        <div class="spacer">
        </div>
    </div>
```

and my css:

```
.testimonial {
background-color: #e6e6e6;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.spacer {
    height: 30px;
}

div.testimonial {
    color: #6f6f6f;
}

div {
    font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}

p {
    text-align: justify
}

.nav-link {
    color: black !important;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: #b13034 !important;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1080px;
}

h1 {
    color: #bf4844
}

p {
    font-size: 18px;
}

.btn-danger {
    background-color: #bf4844;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #15202c;
    color: white;
}

.footer h5 {
    font-size: 12px;
}

.active {
    color: #b13034;
}

h3 {
    color: #bf4844;
    font-size: x-large;
    line-height: 1.3em;
}

.side-testimonial {
    color: #6f6f6f;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.info-header {
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.info-head {
    color: #6f6f6f;
    font-size: large;
}

a {
    color: #b13034;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ff5050
}

.nav a {
    color: white;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: white;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
    border-color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 543px) {
    .navbar .navbar-brand {
        float: none;
    }
}

.side-testimonial i {}


/*
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
*/

.site {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.site-content {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What fixed the issue was adding this to my css:

```
.container-fluid {
margin-right: 0;
margin-left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `container` class so it's take fixed width which bootstrap use for container so change it like below code

Change it

```
<div class="site">
<div class="container my-5 site-content">
```

To

```
<div class="site">
<div class="container-fluid my-5 site-content">
```

CSS changes

```
.testimonial {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
}
```

```css
.testimonial {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
}

.spacer {
  height: 30px;
}

div.testimonial {
  color: #6f6f6f;
}

div {
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}

p {
  text-align: justify
}

.nav-link {
  color: black !important;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: #b13034 !important;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1080px;
}

h1 {
  color: #bf4844
}

p {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.btn-danger {
  background-color: #bf4844;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #15202c;
  color: white;
}

.footer h5 {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.active {
  color: #b13034;
}

h3 {
  color: #bf4844;
  font-size: x-large;
  line-height: 1.3em;
}

.side-testimonial {
  color: #6f6f6f;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.info-header {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}

.info-head {
  color: #6f6f6f;
  font-size: large;
}

a {
  color: #b13034;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ff5050
}

.nav a {
  color: white;
}

.nav a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.navbar-toggler-icon {
  border-color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 543px) {
  .navbar .navbar-brand {
    float: none;
  }
}

.side-testimonial i {}


/*
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
*/

.site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.site-content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="site">
  <div class="container-fluid my-5 site-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="carousel slide" data-interval="9000" data-ride="carousel" id="frontpageCarousel">
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="carousel-item active"><img alt="Giant_head_brighter_500_x_600" class="d-block img-fluid" src="Images/Front-Slideshow/Giant_head_500_x_500.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img alt="final_shot_with_bottle_500_x_600.jpg" class="d-block img-fluid" src="Images/Front-Slideshow/giant_button_500_x_500.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img alt="final_shot_with_bottle_500_x_600.jpg" class="d-block img-fluid" src="Images/Front-Slideshow/two_figures_500_x_500.jpg">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <h1>We build custom props.</h1>
        <p>We utilize a network of the best prop makers in the movie, commercial, trade show, event, advertising, marketing and themed entertainment industries to create amazing props.</p>
        <p>We select the best-suited veteran artisans and fabricators for your project — artisans who fabricate for some of the most popular TV shows, the biggest movies and some of the world’s best known companies, like Disney, Universal Studios, NASA,
          Red Bull, Mazda, JetBlue, Dior and many more.</p>
        <p><b>We're great at what we do and we're here to do it for you.</b>
        </p>
        <div class="text-center">
          <a class=" btn btn-primary" href="request-estimate.html" style="margin-top: 15px">Request an Estimate</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid site-content testimonial">
    <div class="spacer">
    </div>
    <div class="container my-5">
      <p>"Absolutely blown away by your team's work and professionalism. Client thrilled. Great execution. Great teamwork."</p>
      <i>- Project Managers, Derse</i>
      <p>[Derse is ranked as a Top 10 Experiential/Event Marketing Agency by Advertising Age]</p>
    </div>
    <div class="spacer">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The section that is a container-fluid in my html is not inside of a container though.

Comment: Changing that div to fluid only effects the top part, it wont actually effect the testimonial part. If you keep track of the div blocks its not encapsulated in that one you changed.

Comment: I posted css part for  `.testimonial` and it's working fine in chrome see `codepen` link.

Comment: Oooooh, makes sense now. Worked when I set the left and the right margin to 0 for .container-fluid.

Comment: Yes you can, do it, but  it's  a bootstrap class so if you change it will effected every part of site where it's use that's why i changed testimonial class property.